# mysqli_fetch_row How does it work?

Tags: php, mysql

How does this function work? for exaple this loop:

```
while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_row) { 
    do this and that...
}
```

so basically the question is:
Everytime you call this function,it returns the next rows until none it's left,
so if you call it again the condition becomes FALSE right?
SO if you call this function again outside after this loop which row is it going to return?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be quite straightforward to write a test case and see what the result is yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were wondering how this works, the function maintains an internal data pointer which keeps track of the record it is on (just a variable with a number), every time it is called it will increment the pointer by one, in order to set the pointer yourself, you'd want to use the `mysqli_data_seek()` function as already outlined.

Comment: GHHHHHH....the fu..ing pointer so thats what it is. finaly understand it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Once you reach the end of the results, it will keep returning `false`.

If you want to be able to fetch the rows again after the loop, you can use `mysqli_data_seek($result, 0)` to rewind to the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `mysqli_fetch_row()` after that loop will return false since the cursor has reached the end. That's why the loop ends, because at the last iteration the assignment will be for `false` value which will break the loop.

To reset to the beginning of the result set:

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
```

Another alternative is to build an array of rows to be used again:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row) { 
    $data[] = $row;
    do this and that...
}
```

Then you can `foreach` over `$data` later.

Comment: OK, thanks.So is there a way to put he cursor back at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, look at Barmar's answer: `mysqli_data_seek($result, 0)`